# Problem when default page is MainPage.aspx not Default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, config, integrated

I have very strange problem. I'm using IIS 7.0 Integrated mode for my application. (pool is ASP 2.0 integrated)

It's working fine when i type www.xyz.com/MainPage.aspx. But when i used simple www.xyz.com then its not working.

I always get this error

```
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /intranet/default.aspx
```

I have mapped default document to MainPage.aspx still its not working... I don't have default.aspx page in root. only Mainpage.aspx and I can't change it...

my web.config looks like this (only part of it :):

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="MainPage.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you web.config and make sure the default.aspx is not listed as one the default pages. Recycle the app pool and restart IIS.

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <remove value="Default.htm"/>
            <remove value="Default.asp"/>
            <remove value="index.htm"/>
            <remove value="index.html"/>
            <remove value="default.aspx"/>
            <remove value="iisstart.htm"/>
            <add value="MainPage.aspx"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
```

Comment: part of web.config:<system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
  <clear/>
                <add value="MainPage.aspx"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument> so default.aspx should be cleared... when I open IIS manager and open my website/default document I see only MainPage.aspx in the list

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `MainPage.aspx` as default page through [IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615%28WS.10%29.aspx)'s `document` facility. You may also add a default document with [IIS7](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/22/how-to-add-a-default-document-with-iis7-web-config.aspx) web.config.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="MainPage.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this setting is locked in IIS7 on applicationHost.config level. You have to change the root config gile or use IIS Administration API do complete this task.